# Why do flies try to get in my eyes all the time?

Tags: safety

I have flies always trying to get in my eyes and I wear glasses. The flies just fly right into my eye and it stings from where my eyes are dry. Why are they attracted to my eyes?

Comment: We already have a similar question on TGO: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/how-to-deal-with-little-flies-flying-into-the-eyes "You are likely talking about eye flies. They feed on lachrymal secretion which your eyes produce."

Comment: To me they are different questions; Why do they fly in my eyes? How to deal with them? I referenced to other question because one of the answer explains the why.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer moisture and salts.

This is a particular problem if you're in a jungle area, they're isn't much salt in jungles and flies will obtain it form anywhere they can. Humans secrete salts (in sweat).

Answer (score 6):

[Eye flies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloropidae) feed on lachrymal secretion which your [eyes produce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lachrymal_gland).

---

> they feed on lachrymal secretions and other body fluids of various animals, including humans and are of medical significance.

---

> The lacrimal glands are paired almond-shaped glands, one for each eye, that secrete the aqueous layer of the tear film. *[...]* The lacrimal gland produces tears which then flow into canals